# Eclipse not stopping at Debug Breakpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, debugging

I have a simple java, sprint boot project and I wanted to debug the code inside but when I launch the debug, Eclipse doesn't stop at any breakpoint.

I tried to **clean the workspace**, **update maven projects**, **Delete and reimport the project**. try **debugging another project**. I even **changed the eclipse version** but none of these solutions that I found on other StackOverflow posts worked.

Also, the **"Skip All Breakpoints" button is not toggled on**.

I noticed that the callstack is empty and I wonder if the problem may come from it ?

Versions used:

- JDK: 17 Eclipse:
- 2023-09 (4.29.0)
- Spring boot: 3.0.1

Any thoughts ?

Here is the debug view:

[image: Debug view]

Here is the code sample I am trying to debug:

[image: Code Sample]

Here is the maven pom.xml file I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: You're running maven, and maven is launching an entirely new JVM with your actual app. Which is entirely outside of eclipse's "jurisdiction" so to speak, and naturally wouldn't run any breakpoints. I'm not posting this as an answer, because presumably you're looking for "so, how do I fix that?". I don't have experience with m2 plugin / spring boot to tell you, unfortunately.

Comment: A call stack changes continuously during execution and is therefore only displayed for paused threads (hit the _Pause_ button to get the call stack). Please verify that the code is actually called by adding the line `System.out.println("I was here!");` or `System.err.println("I was here!");` before the first break point. What is the reason to run/debug your application via Maven (via the `exec-maven-plugin`? - please show your `pom.xml`) instead of directly?

Comment: Please show your `pom.xml` as text, not as a cropped image.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I run maven from Eclipse not from outside. so normally it should still be under Eclipse's "jurisdiction" ?. But I agree with you upon the fact that it's a maven related issue. I run a JUnit test with a breakpoint, it works just fine.

Comment: @howlger my code is called. the record is well added in H2 database, and also when I add a System.out, it's well displayed. I added the pom.xml as you requested.

Comment: you will probably have to start the application with an option to connect a remote debugger (`-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000` or similar) and create/start a "Remote Java Application" configuration in Eclipse. I do not use Maven, no idea how to do that with it

Comment: @howlger, did the pom.xml as text give you any insights ?

Comment: You run/launch the Maven build script, which in turn executes your Spring Boot application. Better run/debug [the _start-class_](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-main-class#maven) directly (in your `pom.xml` the _start-class_ is not configured; did you specified the _start-class_ via the Maven property [`loader.main`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-main-class#using-cli)?). Remote debugging is not needed, just run your Java application directly.

Comment: @howlger it worked fine, thanx ! I executed the project as a Java application with the main class as an entry point, and not a maven execution. I still don't understand why the maven execution build doesn't work but, the Java app execution worked ! You can add that as an answer so that I Accept it.

Comment: I guess too (as @rzwitserloot suggested also). Although that's not what I would expect since maven is launched from Eclipse. I guess there might be an extra missing configuration somewhere to make the debug work from maven goal, or to "synchronize" the JVM launched by maven and Eclipse if I shall say.

Comment: The forked Java VM child processes are not executed by Maven core, but by a Maven plugin which is not part of Eclipse and which is downloaded into the local Maven repository first. As far as I know, Maven does not provide an API for that. Maven plugins can do what they want and a new version of a plugin can do it in a different way. In case of Maven-Surefire a Maven property tells Surefire to run the tests in debug mode. Surefire prints the info required to attach the debugger to the console from which Eclipse reads it. This works with different and hopefully with upcoming Surefire versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You debug the Maven build script, which in turn executes your Spring Boot application. If the Spring Boot application is executed in a separate (forked) JVM process (like e.g. [Maven-Surefire does](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md#automatically-launch-and-attach-remote-application-debugger-when-maven-plug-in-starts-a-forked-jvm-that-waits-for-a-debugger)), then the application runs in a different Java VM instance than the one you debug (I don't know whether this is actually the case here).

Whatever, better **debug your [Spring Boot start-class](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-main-class#maven) directly as a *Java application***.

Comment: Thanx for your help and your time.